# Name for region in phase space with no outgoing or incoming flows?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I've been looking for a term online but couldnt find it: suppose we have a subset $X$ in phase space, such that for all $q\in X$, the path starting at $q$ never exits $X$ either forward or backward in time.

Is there a name for such an $X$?

Answer (score 1):

A lagrangian submanifold iswhat you are thinking of.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lagrangian+subspace